# Make password protected file/command/executable

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have created executable for .C file and i made that executable as command by moving into /bin directory. now how can i make password protection for that command. it's like whenever we want to run, it should ask for password to execute.and it should work for particular user not all (except root).****

Comment: Check for `uid` in your C code.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how "password protection" works in Linux. There is no such thing, at least not generally. The closest you can do is to check if your `uid` is 0 (running as root) and if not, exit.

Answer (score 6):

That's not the way security works in Unix-like world. The correct way is to restrict execution permission to only some users. If the command shall be accessible to only one user, it must be owned by that user with mode `r-x------`. Alternatively, you can use a custom group and put all users that can use the command in that group. The interesting point here is that the command can still be owned by the `bin` user:

You should use (as root):

```
# chown bin cmd
# chgrp grp cmd
# chmod 0550 cmd
```

That way, only members of group `grp` can use the command `cmd`, and only root can change or remove it. And the command need not receive root priviledges when executed.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you might be interested to setup `sudoers` using command `visudo`. It basically allows to define permissions for users ( with or without password) to execute predefined commands.

For ubuntu, there is an explanation here : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/sudoers

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod 700 <file_path>
```

This allows only you to run, read, and write the file. Root will automatically be able to run it too since it has all permissions.

Edit: you need to do this as the user that you want access for (or run `chown <username> <path>`)